# Staying away from global state with sync callback handlers in AcornJS

Tags: javascript, events, callback, functional-programming

I am using [AcornJS](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) and trying to stay away from global variables. I am looking for a functional paradigm that will allow me to accumulate an array of data from two handlers from the `types.visit` function, `VID` and `VCE`. I managed below to resolve them both to a single function, but what I really need is to accumulate these values as they are discovered. I am trying to do all this without a declared global variable. Is it possible to have a function return an array of many `[type, path]` combinations?

```
const VID = 'visitImportDeclaration'
const VCE = 'visitCallExpression'
const acornVisitCb = (type) => (path) => [type, path]
const getTypesAndPaths = (acornAst) => types.visit(acornAst,{
    [VID]: acornVisitCb(VID),
    [VCE]: acornVisitCb(VCE)
})
```

If it helps, this case is synchronous.

Here's an example of it working, but with defined state 'results'. Can this be done without `results`?

```
function getTypesAndPaths = (acornAst) => {
  const results = []
  types.visit(acornAst, {
    [VID]: (path) => results.push([VID, path])
    [VCE]: (path) => results.push([VCE, path])
  })
  return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {chain} = lodash
const VID = 'visitImportDeclaration'
const VCE = 'visitCallExpression'
const cbPush = (arr, ...top) => (...bot) => arr.push([...top, ...bot])
const getVisitations = (acornPaths) => ({[VID]: cbPush(acornPaths, VID), [VCE]: cbPush(acornPaths, VID)})
const getAcornPaths = (acornAst, acornPaths) => types.visit(acornAst, getVisitations(acornPaths))
const getDependenciesFromAcornAst = (acornAst, acornPaths) => chain(getAcornPaths(acornAst, acornPaths)).thru(() => acornPaths).value()
```